# Video.js need to make full screen without adding allowfullscreen to parent iframe

Tags: video.js

I'm working in an environment where I can't add allowfullscreen to the parent iframe of the page that contains the videojs videos.  Currently, the full screen button does not make the video go full screen.

If I embed a youtube video for instance on the same page it has the ability to go fullscreen.

Is there a way to modify the videojs code to work in a similar way? My javascript knowledge is average so this might be too big for my britches.

Thanks,
Jeff